# Shiro Annotations with Spring

Tags: security, spring-mvc, shiro

i am new to shiro i am integrating shiro with spring and i am trying to use shiro annotations 
on Spring controllers but they are not working , 
the controller stop working when i put the @RequiresPermissions("W027:UPDT") 
on the Controller method . 
any help guys/ 
thanks

Comment: these might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305355/269891 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/6159444/269891

Answer (score 0):

Shiro annotations at controller does not seem to work. To solve this problem you can push @RequiresPermissions("W027:UPDT") to immediate service method (could be dao or service method). This will authorize your controller method indirectly. Trying to use @RequiresPermissions at controller methods means you are trying to protect a particular url. A better approach would be to do that in configuration file rather than in java files.

```
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
         /resources/** = anon
            /login = anon
            /logout = authc             
            /unauthorized = authc
            /someurl/** = roles[ROLE-ADMIN]
            /** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
```